# Is there a difference between the contacts obtained from ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email and Google Contact APIs

Tags: android

On Android, what is (if any) the difference between the contacts that are contained in the `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email` table in the content resolver on one hand, and the contacts we would obtain from the Google Contacts API (People Api) https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started

Can I even use the latter one on Android?